# Green's function on $(\Bbb Z/N \Bbb Z)^d$

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, random-walk

Consider a simple random walk $S_n$ on $\Bbb Z^d$. We write 
$$ g(x,y) = \Bbb E^x \left[ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbf{1}_{\{S_n=y\}}\right]$$
for the expected number of visits to $y$ starting from $x$. This function satisfies the following property:
$$ g(x,y) = \delta_x(y) + \sum_{z\in\Bbb Z^d} p(x,z)g(z,y) = \delta_x(y) + \sum_{z\sim x} p(x,z)g(z,y).$$
Intuitively, this property takes out the first step of the random walk. If $x=y$, then we already have 1 visit, otherwise we consider the random walk from step 2 and onwards, taking into account the probability of starting on the next node. Rewriting this equation a bit, yields:
$$ \sum_{z\sim x} p(x,z) (g(z,y) - g(x,y)) = \Delta g(x,y) = -\delta_x(y), $$
where $\Delta$ is the graph Laplacian.

Consider now a simple random walk $S_n$ on the discrete torus $(\Bbb Z/N\Bbb Z)^d$, and write $g^z(x,y)$ for the expected number of visits to $y$ starting from $x$ before hitting $z$. Now, a paper I'm reading states (very matter-of-factly) that in this case we have
$$ \Delta \frac{g^z(x,y)}{2d} = \delta_z - \delta_x. $$

I'm not really seeing how this is true, if we rewrite this, we get:

$$ g^z(x,y) = \delta_x(y) - \delta_z(y) + \sum_{w\sim y} \frac{g^z(x,w)}{2d}. $$

The first $\delta$-function is intuitively in the right place like before. If we now look at the second $\delta$-function, it only plays a role whenever $z = y$. In this case $g^z(x,y) = g^y(x,y) = 0$, and the above formula should reflect this, meaning (assume $x\neq y$) that
$$ 1 = \sum_{w\sim y} \frac{g^y(x,w)}{2d}. $$

And I don't see how this needs to be true, I explicitly calculated it for a very simple example and it worked, but I honestly do not see how to generalize it. Can someone help me? Maybe I'm stuck in the wrong thought pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(M_n)$ be an ergodic, recurrent Markov chain, on a discrete state space $\Sigma$, with stationnary measure $\mu$. Let $A \subset \Sigma$ be finite. Then, for all $B \subset \Sigma$,

$$\mathbb{E}_A (\# \{(M_n) \text{ hits } B \text{  before going back to A}\}) = \frac{\mu(B)}{\mu(A)},$$

where the expectation is taken with respect to $\mu_{|A} / \mu(A)$. This is a consequence of the stationnarity of the measure $\mu$. Note that this also holds for $B \subset A$, as then $M_0 \in B$ with probability $\mu (B) / \mu (A)$.

For reference: [see this pdf](https://www.math.kth.se/matstat/gru/sf3953/Material/L7.pdf) (althoug $\mu$ doesn't need to be a probability measure).

Now, let's consider your problem. $\mu$ is the uniform measure on $\Sigma = (\mathbb{Z}_{/N\mathbb{Z}})^d$. The above can be reframed as:

$$g^A (A,B) = \frac{\mu (B)}{\mu(A)}.$$

Taking $A := \{y\}$ and $B := \{w: w \sim y\}$, we get:

$$g^y (y,B) = 2d.$$

But, starting from $y$, the first step is to $B$, and it hits $B$ uniformly, so:

$$g^y (y,B) = \frac{1}{2d} \sum_{w \sim y} g^y (w, B) = g^y (B, B) = 2d.$$

By symmetry, for all $w \in B$, we have $g^y (B, B) = g^y (w, B) = 2d$.

Finally, starting from $x \neq y$, let $W$ be the point where the random walk first hits $B$. Then:

$$g^y (x,B) = \sum_{w \sim y} g^y(x,w) = \sum_{w \sim y} \mathbb{P}_x (W = w) g^y (w,B) = 2d.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I don't see how we can get $g^y(y,B) \neq 0$. Since this $(g^y(y,B) = 0)$ is what I used to derive the final equation in my question, however you have $g^y(y,B) = 2d$ but still arrived at the same conclusion as I did with $\sum_{w\sim y} g^y(x,w) = 2d$.

Comment: @TheBrainletExterminator: for $x$, $y$, $w$, I define $\varphi^y := \inf \{n \geq 1: S_n = y\}$ and $g^y (x,w) = \mathbb{E}_x (\# \{k < \varphi^y: S_n = z\})$. Then, to compute $g^y (y,B)$, I start from $y$, and count how many time I go through $B$ before going back to $y$. Note that, if $y \in B$, then $k=0$ counts, so $g^y (y,B) \leq 1$. If you use a different definition, I think you can still adapt what I wrote to your setting.

Comment: Yes thank you I now see why this is true! We have according to the article you referenced $g^A(A,B) = \frac{\mu(B)}{\mu(A)} = 2d$. But this is starting from $A$, and NOT counting the first iteration. We really see that in my notation, this is equal to
$$ g^A(A,B) = \sum_{w\sim y} g^y(x,w) =2d.$$
And this is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot man.